# Is the grad parameter of custom gradient ops in Tensorflow always a matrix of ones?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning

As far as I am concerned there are two ways of creating custom ops like follows:

```
@tf.RegisterGradient("CustomGrad")
    def _custom_grad(op, grad):
        return grad
```

and

```
@function.Defun(tf.float32, tf.float32)
    def bprop(op, grad):
        return grad

@function.Defun(tf.float32, grad_func=bprop)
    def fprop(W):
        W = tf.sign(W)
        return W
```

I appears to me that regardless of which type of computation for the forward prop the `grad` parameter of the custom gradient op is always a matrix of ones. I think it kinda makes sense because you can just use the custom gradient op to let the gradient pass through. However, I need confirmation.

Can someone confirm or correct?

Answer (score 0):

`grad` is the input gradient from the next instance in the graph after your op with the custom gradient. It is not affected by the forward pass of your op. If you change what happens after the op the `grad` can change.